# Xamarin Android , sometimes requesting GPS location need network connection

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am implementing an APP with Xamarin.

In my APP I have set access fine location permission.

And in runtime I have allow the permission.

But sometimes, the APP still can't get the GPS location infomation.
(This happens in a low possiblity)

But once connect the phone to a network(router).

The GPS works again.

What would be the reason?

Here is code I use

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;    
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
```

Comment: Location isn't GPS.  It can be, but other ways of getting location include wifi and cell networks.  You'd need to post your code for us to know what your're actually using

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Just added my code.

Comment: Sometimes the device just can’t get a good GPS signal.  Having WiFi enabled allows it to use alternate methods to determine location.

Comment: You'd need to dive into the source code of the library, but it mentions network location in its permission set.